# Why does main() have to return an int?

Tags: c++

In most cases `int main()` does not return anything, it doesn't even have to since no `return` would not give an error. So why does main have to return an int? Why is void main not possible?

EDIT: I meant, why is int main() the standard if there usually is no `return`?

Comment: because there's an implicit return in main even when you don't write it.

Comment: Here int contains two value either 0 or 1. 0 means your program successfully executed ,where 1 means termination of program with some error. And this value is returned to OS.

Comment: @SudeshKumar, You can return numbers other than 0 or 1...

Comment: @SudeshKumar - the only number you can return is 0. There are two manifest constants that you can return: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`; the language definition doesn't say what the values of those constants are.

Comment: @chirs you are right :) even i'm also tested with character. Beacuse character also converted into numeric value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other programs may use the return code to determine whether the application executed successfully.  Zero typically means successful execution.

Answer (score 8):

`void` is possible but non-standard. The returned `int` is meant to signify something for the caller.

Comment: In C++, `void main()` violates the standard; the standard _requires_ the return type of `int` with no wriggle room.

Answer (score 4):

The same way as a function in your program may returns values to indicate its result, `main` returns to indicate the result of execution of your program.

Also in case `int main()` does return explicit, compiler will put `return 0` automatically